# hive: filter by "max(partitioned_col)" without performing full table scan

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a large Hive table partitioned by date, and I'm trying to setup an Oozie workflow that runs a process on the most recent partition. Each time the ETL job runs a new folder is created. The directory structure looks like this:

```
/user/hive/warehouse/my_transactions/date=20150424
[...]
/user/hive/warehouse/my_transactions/date=20150811
/user/hive/warehouse/my_transactions/date=20150812
/user/hive/warehouse/my_transactions/date=20150813
```

On my home/lab cluster, running Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.4.4, I'm able to use the `max` aggregate function in a subquery to filter for the most recent days data:

```
select
  [...]
from my_transactions
inner join (select max(date) as max_date from my_transactions) max_date
on date = max_date
```

The results are returned pretty quickly.

In our work environment, running Hive 0.13.0-mapr-1501 on a much larger dataset with beefier hardware, the same query attempts to execute in multiple stages and eventually throws a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

If I replace the subquery with a literal, i.e. `WHERE date = '20150813'` instead of the aggregation and the inner join, it executes really quickly. With the aggregation/subquery it seems like, instead of using the partitions to reduce the amount of IO, it's attempting to scan all the partitions.

Is there a better way to write this query (e.g. possibly query the Hive metadata to get the `max(date)` of the partitioned column)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you run an EXPLAIN on your query, to understand how Hive tries to translate that JOIN into sub-tasks?

All right, EXPLAIN output is a dirty mess, but I suspect that it would show an awkward query plan such as...

- dumping the **entire left-side** table into the RAM (i.e. a Java HashMap) of each Mapper
- then reading sequentially the result of the **right-side** subquery (1 record) to match each record against the HashMap

It would be typical of a MAPJOIN in the wrong order.
So, what about replacing that dummy `JOIN` with a more explicit `WHERE IN (subquery)` that is [supported at last in Hive 0.13](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries#LanguageManualSubQueries-SubqueriesintheWHEREClause)?

Bottom line: the Hive query optimizer is still a crude and vicious beast. In many cases you have to steer it to the "correct" query plan.

Answer (score -1):

This query gives the max(partitioned column) without scanning the entire table.

```
hive -e "set hive.cli.print.header=false;show partitions table_name;" | tail -1 | cut -d'=' -f2
```

Comment: how do you provide this value to your query being executed from another program, say from HUE? From what i understand that would again require some kind of custom value injection.

Comment: Yes.. you'll have to use value injection through shell script with this approach.